# Rails 4 - Validation based on Multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have USERS, CATEGORIES and WORKGROUPS.  A user belongs to a workgroup: user.workgroup_id.  A category belongs to a workgroup: category.workgroup_id.  WORKGROUP has many users and categories.

I need to write a model validation that disallows assigning a category.workgroup_id where no existing user has that particular workgroup_id, with an error message like, "Sorry, but no one belongs to that workgroup, so you may not assign it to this Category."

Any advice?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workgroup

  validate :workgroup_not_empty, if: Proc.new { workgroup_id_changed? }

  def workgroup_not_empty
    if workgroup.users.count == 0
      errors.add(:workgroup_id, "Sorry, but no one belongs to that workgroup, so you may not assign it to this Category.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, but got the following error:  `undefined method changed? for 10:Fixnum`

Comment: Thanks - I also changed it to validate :on => :create/:update... is that not good practice?

Comment: Could I also create a scope method on WORKGROUP indicating whether it is empty, then call Workgroup.not_empty to populate my select list ...?  Hmm, thanks!

Comment: Of course you should do that, I just didn't want to overload the answer with non related details.

Comment: Heh - I'm always open to better ideas.  Thanks for sparking one, in addition to giving me the answer.  :)

Comment: Hey, how would I do that cleanly in the WORKGROUP model, btw?  How would I define a scope of workgroup.populated where user.workgroup_id.exists?